# Traversal through a string with a loop in Python

Tags: python

My code below is not generalized; it handles each line of output as a special case.  How I could get the same output using a while or for statement?

```
string = "Apple"
i = 0

one = string[0:i+1]
two = string[0:i+2]
three = string[0:i+3]
four = string[0:i+4]
five = string[0:i+5]

print(one)
print(two)
print(three)
print(four)
print(five)
```

I have the following result:

```
A
Ap
App
Appl
Apple
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With a for loop:

```
for i in range(len(string)):
    print(string[0:i+1])
```

With a while loop:

```
j = 0
while j < len(string):
    j += 1
    print(string[0:j])
```

Answer (score 1):

In Python we can iterate through a string to get the individual characters.

```
output = ''
for letter in 'Apple':
    output += letter
    print (output)
```

Comment: you do not need the semicolon at the end of each statement, and though you produce the correct output you are constantly creating a string at every iteration.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I am aware we create a new string, but string slices are just as expensive, and I feel less readable.

Answer (score 1):

Note that your variable **i** is useless: you set it to **0** and then use it only to add to things.  Dump it.

This is a simple usage of the loop index:

```
for i in range(len(string)):
    print string[0:i+1]
```

Note that you can drop the **0** from the print statement.